# Example of a group of order 80 with more than one Sylow 5-subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I have noticed that it can be 1 or 16 Sylow-5 subgroups. I have provided an example of group $G$ where there is 1 Sylow-5 subgroup. It is $\mathbb Z_{80}$. But I don't know what to do if there are 16 Sylow-5 subgroups. Is there an example of such a group?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of group G, where there are 64 elements of order 5? That was the point of my question.

Comment: I'd suggest, emil, that you edit your "question" to provide more details regarding what you are actually asking. Because you comment above, (and the same comment left below each of the two answers you received) is not the question (which was never entirely clear) you are trying to ask in your post, nor in the title of your post.

Comment: @emil I edited the title and added the final sentence to bring the question in line with your apparent intent. Please edit if this is not what you intended.

Answer (score 3):

Let $H = \mathbb Z_5$ and $K = \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$.

Since $|\operatorname{Aut}(K)| = (2^4 - 1)(2^4-2)(2^4-2^2)(2^4-2^3)$ is divisible by $5$, there exists a nontrivial homomorphism $\phi : H \to \operatorname{Aut}(K)$, e.g. map a generator of $H$ to a generator of any subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ of order $5$.

Hence there exists a semidirect product $G = H \ltimes_{\phi} K$ where $K \lhd G$. Since $\phi$ is nontrivial, this is not a direct product, hence $H$ is not normal, hence there must be more than one Sylow $5$-subgroup, so by Sylow counting, there must be $16$ such subgroups.

Answer (score -1):

Each subgroup of order $5$ has $4$ elements of order $5$, and any two such subgroups have a trivial intersection. Hence, in this case, there are $4\times 16=64$ elements of order $5$.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of group G, where there are 64 elements of order 5? That was the point of my question.

Comment: @emil You did not state that you were looking for a particular group; the phrasing of the actual question just suggests you wanted to *count* elements in the "16 subgps of order 5" case.